# Select all text in one click (not editable)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to disable text editability after selection, but setting contenteditable to false does not work.

```
<div class="block" contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/15/

Add `disabled` attribute

```
document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute("contenteditable", "false");
```

Comment: That's invalid. You should set `disabled` property to boolean value, but not the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple try like below....

Set `contenteditable="false"` in your div attribute...

its working fine for me in chrome, firefox and IE

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GZNYc/6/

Comment: @Rndpbs : Which browser you are trying...?

Comment: It just selects all text on my page.
I'm using chrome.